# How do I avoid the fixtures not found error in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to conduct a workflow test in pytest.

```
def test_workflow():
    with open("./configs.json",'r') as f:
        CONFIGS = json.load(f)
    owner_id = CONFIGS['ownerId']
    project_name = CONFIGS['projectConfigs']['projectName']
    project_configs = CONFIGS['projectConfigs']
    project_configs['ownerId']  = owner_id


    projectId = test_project_creation(
        owner_id= owner_id,
        project_configs = project_configs,
        application_configs = CONFIGS['applicationConfigs'][CONFIGS['applicationName']],
    ) 

    input_video, output_ip, output_port, output_hls_link, input_hls_link = test_create_streams(
        input_stream_config=CONFIGS['inputStreamConfigs']
    )
```

Where I have a `test_workflow()` method that calls the various steps inside. Now the output of one testing step is being passed to others. When I run this in pytest, all the methods run properly but I get an error stating that `fixtures not found`. Is there a way to get around this or suppress it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that pytest thinks that test_project_creation is a separate test which requires fixtures named owner_id and the others. Try to rename test_project_creation and other functions starting with test_ (except test_workflow) to something which doesn't starts with test_ (like create_project())

Comment: But they are technically "tests". I want the result of all steps to be included in the pytest report

Comment: I think in this case you'd better reorganize test_workflow module. Create a fixture or multiple fixtures containing the data you are reading from config file (first 6 lines of the test_workflow) and create separate tests like test_project_creation, test_create streams, etc which use those fixtures. Maybe you'll have to use pytest-order plugin to specify the order which tests are run.

Comment: Or you can use a different approach - use some advanced reporting tool like allure to display steps in your test report